# how execute curl in mariadb/mysql stored procedure

Tags: curl, mysql, mariadb

I am using information from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28665934/invoking-an-http-get-request-through-mysql-by-executing-native-operating-system) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55241615/mysql-sys-exec-cant-open-shared-library-lib-mysqludf-sys-so-errno-11-wrong).

I am running mariadb server on Debian 10.  I download and copied the files to the server and execute the install.sh  and I get the following error below.

```
"compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:4: install] Error 1
ERROR: You need libmysqlclient development software installed
to be able to compile this UDF, on Debian/Ubuntu just run:
apt-get install libmysqlclient15-dev"
```

So I executed `apt-get install libmysqlclient15-dev` to install the libmysqlclient development software.  But then I get the error `Unable to locate package libmysqlclient15-dev`.

I tried everything to install that library but I am stuck there.

Please kindly help me again..  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`libmysqlclient15-dev` is not available in recent Debian releases anymore.

Instead of mysql, mariadb is used. Try to install the package `default-libmysqlclient-dev` which installs the `libmariadb-dev-compat` package that should be at least somehow compatible with the origin mysql packages.

You might need to adapt the install script to support it.

Comment: jofel, thanks for reply.  I already tried installing that default-libmysqlclient-dev package but I still get the same error upon executing install.sh

Comment: Or if is not available in Debian distro, is libmysqlclient15-dev available in latest Ubuntu release?